# probability of A or B or A and B

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading Probability tutorial and found this question and answer.

A student goes to the library. The probability that she checks out (a) a work of fiction is 0.40, (b) a work of non-fiction is 0.30, and (c) both fiction and non-fiction is 0.20. What is the probability that the student checks out a work of fiction, non-fiction, or both?

Solution: Let F = the event that the student checks out fiction; and let N = the event that the student checks out non-fiction. Then, based on the rule of addition:

P(F ∪ N) = P(F) + P(N) - P(F ∩ N) 
P(F ∪ N) = 0.40 + 0.30 - 0.20 = 0.50

According to me,
as it is told to "checks out a work of fiction, non-fiction, or both"
so probability is "Fiction union Non-fiction union both" which it should be     ( F u N u (F n N) ) but it is told as (fiction union non-fiction) is answer.

I got a reference from this [link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120303034626AAadNPD) here in answer section

```
P(A or B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A & B)=0.5 
P(A or B or (A & B))
=P((A or B) or (A & B))
=P(A or B)+P(A & B)-P((A or B)&(A & B))
=P(A or B)+P(A & B)-P(A & B) --> how P((A or B)&(A & B)) became P(A & B) here
=P(A or B)=0.5
```

Comment: What do you mean, the equation should be $P((F\cup N)\cup(F\cap N))$? "$P((F\cup N)\cup(F\cap N))$" is not an equation; there is no $=$ sign in it.

Comment: Correctly: $P(F\cup N)=P(F)+P(N)-P(F\cap N)=0.40+0.30-0.20=0.50,$ while $P(F)+P(N)-P(F\cap N)P(F\cup N)=0.40+0.30-(0.20)(0.50)=0.60\ne P(F\cup N).$

Comment: $F\cup N\cup(F\cap N)=F\cup N$

Comment: @bof: I read that P(F ∪ N) = P(F) + P(N) – P(F ∩ N) .. does F∪N∪(F∩N) is same as P(F) + P(N) – P(F ∩ N)? Union is + and Intersection is multiplication right.

Comment: Observe that $\;F\cap N\subset F\cup N\;$ , and thus $\;P(F\cup N\cup(F\cap N))=P(F\cup N)\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the choice is random and the events are independent, and using your notation:

$$\begin{cases}P(F)=0.4\\{}\\P(N)=0.3\\{}\\P(F\cap N)=0.2\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\;P(F\cup N)=P(F)+P(N)-P(F\cap N)=0.5$$

Observe that $\;F\cup N\;$ is the event that either fiction or non fiction **or both** happens (i.e., is chosen). Unless otherwise explicitly stated, "or" in mathematics is always inclusive.

Comment: got it. I read that F u N is either F happens or N happens but as you mentioned it is F u N or both happens. still 1 doubt. both happens is F n B right?

Comment: can someone please explain why negative vote for this answer, does understanding wrote on this answer is wrong?

Comment: @Jayesh Unfortunately there are "rogue downvoters" or even "serial downvoters" in this site, who downvote just because. Most probably you won't get an answer to your above comment. You must  apply what you know and the data you gave and deduce whether my answer is wrong or right.

Comment: To be very honest, even your answer got down vote, I am very clear by your answer only. when i wrote I am learning and confused in understanding the solution gave by someone, still the question got downvote.

Answer (score 1):

> According to me, as it is told to "checks out a work of fiction, non-fiction, or both" so probability is "Fiction union Non-fiction union both" which it should be ( F u N u (F n N) ) but it is told as (fiction union non-fiction) is answer.

The symbol $\cup$ stands for "union" (a.k.a. "disjunction") of the events, and it means "inclusive or".   It includes the intersection (a.k.a "conjunction", symbol $\cap$).  So "fiction union non-fiction" is "fiction, or non-fiction, or both".

The symbol $\oplus$ stands for "exclusive disjunction", or "xor".  It excludes the intersection.  So "fiction xor non-fiction" would be "either fiction or non-fiction but not both"

---

**tl;dr**  $(F\cup N)\cup(F\cap N)\\ = (F\cup N\cup F)\cap(F\cup N\cup N)\\ = (F\cup N)\cap(F\cup N)\\ = F\cup N$

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that 
 P((F ∪ N) ∪ (F ∩ N)) should be the LHS of the equation?

But if some event x is in (F ∩ N), then it is in F and in N and therefore it is also in (F ∪ N). So why do you want to take the union of the two sets?

Comment: I didn't got your point. might be I am not clear in my explanation, so I have edited it, can you please share your thought now.

Answer (score 0):

If we formulate probabilities over sets of outcomes, then you can use the algebraic laws of $\cap$ and $\cup$:

$$ P((F \cup N) \cup (F \cap N)) $$

Associate on $\cup$: $(A \cup B) \cup C = A \cup (B \cup C)$

$$ P(F \cup (N \cup (F \cap N)) $$

Commute on $\cap$: $A \cap B = B \cap A$

$$ P(F \cup (N \cup (N \cap F)) $$

Absorbtion on $\cup$ over $\cap$: $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$

$$ P(F \cup N) $$